# The result of rendering cycles is not the same color as Eevee in blender 2.9

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, color

Recently I followed a tutorial on youtube about modeling a stage, here is the tutorial link: https://youtu.be/9r6WX_rPf3E

The Eevee results were as expected, but when I rendered on Cycles, the metallic colors changed.

**[Render Eevee]**

[image]

**[Render Cycles]**

[image]

in the tutorial, the results of the cycles are darker, but in my project the result in rendering cycles is brighter (The tutorial results when in cycles mode: https://youtu.be/9r6WX_rPf3E?t=1166). I've also changed the power of the lamp and the Strength of the HDRI but it still doesn't work.

### Settings

*Eevee settings*

[image]

*Cycles settings*

[image]

Is there anything I need to add/remove to achieve the same result as the tutorial above? (More dark in cycles) Thanks!

Comment: Emission materials could affect on lightning in Cycles, but it is not so in EEVEE, it doesn't support mesh-lights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I managed to get what I wanted**. The error is very simple.

In my blue metallic material somehow it doesn't turn blue.

[image]

After I changed the metal value, the color changed.

[image]

**[Render results in cycles mode]**

[image]

Maybe this will be my lesson that I have to be more careful. Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Try darkening the environment and adding some volumetric scatter in order to imitate the bloom from Eevee.If you don't want to dare the environment, a navy blue/grey/black metallic shader from the principled BSDF may work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)